# SQL Server sending blank email

Tags: sql, sql-server

For testing purposes, I did not pass any statement. But, I still get a blank email (test email comes in just fine). I tried the same code on different other servers and it works and prints the information. Below is the code. I added PRINT statement to see if shows me anything, no luck.

```
DECLARE @FQDN varchar (25)
DECLARE @Domain NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @EventTime NVARCHAR (25)
DECLARE @Instance NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @NLCR AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

EXEC master.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters', N'Domain',@Domain OUTPUT

SET @FQDN = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') as nvarchar) + '.' + @Domain
SET @Instance = @@SERVICENAME
SET @EventTime = GETDATE()

DECLARE @strsubject varchar(100)
SELECT @strsubject = 'JDE Submitted Jobs in Error'

DECLARE @tableHTML  nvarchar(max);
SET @tableHTML =
    N'<H1>JDE Submitted Jobs in Error </H1>' + @NLCR +
    N'<b>Server Name: </b>'+ @FQDN + @NLCR +' <br>' + 
    N'<b>Instance Name: </b>'+ @Instance + @NLCR +' <br>' +
    N'<b>Event Time: </b>' + @EventTime + @NLCR +' <br>' +
    N'<br>' +       
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<tr><th>Queue</th><th>Status</th>' +
    N'<th>Env</th><th>User</th>' +
    N'<th>Job #</th><th>Description</th>' +
    N'<th>Actual Date</th><th>Actual Time</th>' +
    N'<th>Host</th></tr>' +
            N'</table>' 
    ;

PRINT @tableHTML
```

Comment: Be sure no value in the concatenated string is null. 'ABC' + NULL = NULL

Comment: Select all your variables after you have finished populating them and verify that they have the desired values. You cannot debug code if you don't know what values it is producing. And for future reference, "no luck" is not a useful description of any issue or outcome. You can see what you are doing and what is happening - but no one else can.

Comment: Thank you all. Apparently Server Name was not being retrieved, therefore sending a blank email.

Comment: I'm gald you sorted it. In future, please note statements like _I added PRINT statement to see if shows me anything, no luck_, are not useful. Did the PRINT statement print anything or not?

Comment: At first, the PRINT did not print anything. Once I commented on the Server Name line, it printed as expected. Come to find out the server was not capturing Domain name so I added the following: SET @Domain = 'DOMAIN NAME'  and commented EXEC master.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters', N'Domain',@Domain OUTPUT. After that, the whole thing worked as expected.